# VBA in Excel - using text box string as cell reference

Tags: vba, excel

How would one use the contents of a text box to reference a specific cell? I would like to be able to enter a cell range (`A1:A10`, for instance) into two text boxes and then apply a function to that specific range of cells.

Answer (score 1):

```
Range(textBox1.Text & ":" & textBox2.Text)
```